# What is the fastest way to insert data to MS SQL database without locking it?

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I've a running system where data is inserted periodically into MS SQL DB and web application is used to display this data to users.

During data insert users should be able to continue to use DB, unfortunatelly I can't redesign the whole system right now. Every 2 hours 40k-80k records are inserted.

Right now the process looks like this:

1. Temp table is created
2. Data is inserted into it using plain INSERT statements (parameterized queries or stored proceuders should improve the speed).
3. Data is pumped from temp table to destination table using `INSERT INTO MyTable(...) SELECT ... FROM #TempTable`

I think that such approach is very inefficient. I see, that insert phase can be improved (bulk insert?), but what about transfering data from temp table to destination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is waht we did a few times. Rename your table as TableName_A. Create a view that calls that table. Create a second table exactly like the first one (Tablename_B). Populate it with the data from the first one. Now set up your import process to populate the table that is not being called by the view. Then change the view to call that table instead. Total downtime to users, a few seconds. Then repopulate the first table. It is actually easier if you can truncate and populate the table becasue then you don't need that last step, but that may not be possible if your input data is not a complete refresh.

Comment: It seems I have a lot of data in that table already. It seems copying it will take some time too.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot avoid locking when inserting into the table. Even with BULK INSERT this is not possible.

But clients that want to access this table during the concurrent INSERT operations can do so when changing the transaction isolation level to READ UNCOMMITTED or by executing the SELECT command with the WITH NOLOCK option.

The INSERT command will still lock the table/rows but the SELECT command will then ignore these locks and also read uncommitted entries.